# Quotient of Gamma functions

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I am trying to find a clever way to compute the quotient of two gamma functions whose inputs differ by some integer. In other words, for some real value $x$ and an integer $n < x$, I want to find a way to compute

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)} $$

For $n=1$, the quotient it is simply $(x-1)$ since by definition

$$ \Gamma(x) = (x - 1)\Gamma(x-1) $$

For $n=2$, it is also simple:

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-2)} = 
\frac{(x-1)\Gamma(x-1)}{\Gamma(x-2)} =
(x-1)(x-2)$$

If we continue this pattern out to some arbitrary $n$, we get

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)} = \prod_i^n (x-i)$$

Obviously I am floundering a bit here. Can anyone help me find an efficient way to compute this quotient besides directly computing the two gamma functions and dividing?

I am also okay if an efficient computation can be found in log space. Currently I am using a simple approximation of the log gamma function and taking the difference. This was necessary because the gamma function gets too big to store in any primitive data type for even smallish values of $x$.

Comment: Taking logarithms and using Stirling's approximation?

Comment: What you have does look like a [falling factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html)...

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean
$$ \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - i) $$
Of course this might not be very nice if $n$ is very large, in which case you might want to first compute the $\Gamma$ values and divide; but then (unless $x$ is very close to one of the integers $i$) the result will also be enormous.  If you're looking for a numerical approximation rather than an exact value, you can use Stirling's approximation
or its variants.

EDIT: Note also that if your $x$ or $x-n$ might be negative, you may find the reflection formula useful:
$$ \Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} $$

For $x > n$, 
$$ \eqalign{\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)}\right) &= n \ln x + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x-i)\cr
&= n \ln x + \sum_{i=1}^n \left( - \frac{i}{x} - \frac{i^2}{2x^2} - \frac{i^3}{3x^3} - \frac{i^4}{4x^4} - \frac{i^5}{5x^5} - \frac{i^6}{6 x^6}\ldots \right)\cr
&= n \ln x - \frac{n(n+1)}{2x} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12 x^2} - \frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{12 x^3} \cr
& -{\frac {n \left( n+
1 \right)  \left( 2\,n+1 \right)  \left( 3\,{n}^{2}+3\,n-1 \right) }{120 {
x}^{4}}}-\frac { \left( n+1 \right) ^{2}{n}^{2}
 \left( 2\,{n}^{2}+2\,n-1 \right) }{60 {x}^{5}}
\ldots} $$
This provides excellent approximations as $x \to \infty$ for fixed $n$ (or $n$ growing much more slowly than $x$).
On the other hand, for $n = tx$ with $0 < t < 1$ fixed, as $x \to \infty$ we have

$$ \eqalign{\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)}\right) &=(1-t) x \ln(x) - (t \ln(t) - t + 1) x +\frac{\ln(t)}{2}\cr &+{
\frac {t-1}{12tx}}+{\frac {1-{t}^{3}}{360{t}^{3}{x}^{3}}
}+{\frac {{t}^{5}-1}{1260{t}^{5}{x}^{5}}}+\frac{1-t^7}{1680 t^7 x^7} \ldots 
}$$

Comment: Thank you for the fix - I've edited my question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to stipulate that $n < x$, which is the case for my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the expression in terms of the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) as

$$ (x-1)_n = \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-n)}. $$

Comment: Nifty - I hadn't heard of the Pochhammer symbol before. Now, if only I knew how to calculate it...

Comment: @jlund3: It is used in the hypergeometric functions and has some useful properties.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the downvote for?

Comment: My guess is that it was downvoted because it just gave a name to the desired expression and did not help in any way with the desired evaluation.

Comment: @martycohen: The OP found it useful!

Comment: @Downvoter - its true he didn't give me a way to directly compute, but he certainly aided my Google searches with new vocabulary!

Comment: So maybe it would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: *What's the downvote for?* You know very well that you do not care.