# A limit of the hypergeometric function

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, hypergeometric-function

I am hardly a mathematician, but I am trying to compute (in R, if that matters) and for $s, v > 0$ the expression

$_2F_1(s, s, s + 1, -v) \cdot v^s / s$.

(Why? I want to to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{(1 + \exp(-x))^s} dx$ over real $x$ and $s$, and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%281+%2F+%281+%2B+exp%28-x%29%29%5Es%29) gave me this expression.)

For most numbers, this works fine. I hit problems when "$v = \infty$" (that is, $v > 1e308$), which I solved using the approximation

$\ln(v) - \psi(s) - \gamma$, which I can compute since $v = \exp(x)$.

Now, I hit further trouble in other extreme cases, e.g., $(v, s) = (1e4, 100)$. In this case, the result is approximately 4.04 ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2F1%28100%2C%20100%2C%20101%2C%20-1e4%29%20*%201e4%5E100%20%2F%20100)), but of course I won't find that since $v^s = 1e400 >> 1e308$. Similarly, I won't be able to find the result of $_2F_1(s, s, s + 1, -v)$: it's pretty much zero for any standard floating point number.

So now I am looking for another approximation for large $s$, and I thought about looking at

$\lim_{s \to \infty} {_2}F_1(s, s, s + 1, -v) \cdot v^s / s$

or

$\lim_{s \to \infty} {_2}F_1(s, s, s + 1, -v) \cdot v^s$.

Can this be simplified? Or will this help in any other way?

Comment: I would first look at the linear transformation formulas; e.g., Digital Library of Mathematical Functions,  15.8.1  One transformation puts the argument in the form of $-v/(1+v),$ which is close to -1 for large positive $v.$  Another formula, 15.8.2, puts the argument in terms of $1/v,$ so if $v$ is always large,$s$ bounded and not an integer, then the sum will be short and easy to calculate. Finally, it appears you have a situation where $v$ and $s$ are both large, so you may need to consult section 15.12.

Comment: @skbmoore thanks, this helped big time! fyi, the key thing (for me) with transformation 15.8.1 is not that the $-v$ parameter is transformed, but that the large $v^s$ factor is (almost completely) integrated. (It's probably the same argument, but intuitively it's two different things to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared as a comment, and upon the proper's suggestion, has been converted to an answer:

I would first look at the linear transformation formulas; e.g., Digital Library of Mathematical Functions, 15.8.1 One transformation puts the argument in the form of −v/(1+v), which is close to -1 for large positive v. Another formula, 15.8.2, puts the argument in terms of 1/v, so if v is always large,s bounded and not an integer, then the sum will be short and easy to calculate. Finally, it appears you have a situation where v and s are both large, so you may need to consult section 15.12

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

Years ago, I faced a similar problem for large $v$ and used (almost from definition)
$$\, _2F_1(s,s;s+1;-v)\,\frac{v^s }{s}=\log(1+v)-\psi (s)-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^p(-1)^n\frac{ n!-\frac{\Gamma (n+s)}{\Gamma (s)}}{n\, n!}\frac 1 {v^n}+O\left(\frac{1}{v^{p+1}}\right)$$ which, at least for my needs, converges quite fast.

Trying for $v=10^4$ and $s=10^2$, as a function of $p$, we get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{result} \\
 1 & 4.042962849 \\
 2 & 4.042937604 \\
 3 & 4.042937662 \\
 4 & 4.042937661
\end{array}
\right)$$
Trying for $v=10^4$ and $s=10^4$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.4228343309 \\
 2 & 0.1728093359 \\
 3 & 0.2283815593 \\
 4 & 0.2179586415 \\
 5 & 0.2196269754 \\
 6 & 0.2193951465 \\
 7 & 0.2194235507 \\
 8 & 0.2194204418 \\
 9 & 0.2194207491 \\
 10 & 0.2194207214 \\
 11 & 0.2194207237 \\
 12 & 0.2194207236
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Doing what you suggest in comments, this could also write as
$$\, _2F_1(s,s;s+1;-v)\,\frac{v^s }{s}=\log(v)-\psi (s)-\gamma+s\sum_{n=1}^p (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ (s+1)_{n-1}}{n\,n!}\frac 1 {v^n}+O\left(\frac{1}{v^{p+1}}\right)$$ What we can notice is that, for large values of $s$
$$\frac{ (s+1)_{n-1}}{n\,n!}=(n-1)\log(s)+O\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$$

Comment: This does help for sure to confirm the large-$v$ approximation that I am using (which took me almost a day to derive and I was never 100% confident it's correct) - thanks! For large $v^s$, I now resort to @skbmoore's solution because it allows me to continue to use the `hypergeo` R package.

Comment: Useful by the way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252786/quotient-of-gamma-functions

Comment: Using this for the totality of large-$s$ cases, one downside of this is that it works only for large $v$. I still have to figure out when I can safely use this, it fails even for $v>1$ cases (e.g., $v=2$, $s=100$).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I feel your expression can be simplified by using $log(1+v) = log(v) + 1/v - 1/(2v^2) + 1/(3v^3) ...$, compare https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor%5Blog%281%2Bv%29%5D. Then, you replace $log(1+v)$ by $log(v)$ and remove $n!$ from the numerator.